# Kendo UI ASP.Net MVC ForeignKey column DataSource in InCell Edit mode

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have Kendo Grid and a ForeignKey column on a page.  ForeignKey column is populated using ViewData as described below.

```
column.ForeignKey(x => x.ProductID, (List<Product>)ViewData["products"], "ID", "ProdName");
```

The Grid is editable in batch(InCell) mode as show below...

```
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell)
```

I want to modify collection of ProductID column in the grid after page is loaded based on value selected on other drop-down defined outside of the Grid.

How can I achieve that?  Can I do it using jQuery?

Similar example I found here...
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/cascading-dropdowns-in-grid-edit---foreignkey-columns.aspx

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out how to filter the Product drop-down using an EditorTemplate for the foreign key column.

Here is my **column definition** for the Product.

```
c.ForeignKey(x => x.ProductID, (List<Product>)ViewData["products"], "ID", "ProdName").EditorTemplateName("ProductIDEditor");
```

Here is the **editor template** for Product, ProductIDEditor.cshtml

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
    .AutoBind(false)
    .OptionLabel("Select a value...")
    .DataTextField("ProdName")
    .DataValueField("ID")
    .DataSource(dataSource =>
    {
        dataSource.Read(read => read.Action("FilterProducts", "Home").Data("filterProducts"))
        .ServerFiltering(true);
    })                                   
)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m)
```

In my main **VIEW** Index.cshtml, I added `filterProducts` JavaScript handler, that passes JSON object for `productID` to controller.

```
function filterChargeTypes()
{
    return {
        productID: $("#ProductID").val()
    };
}
```

Here is the **controller** that listens to filtering event...

```
public ActionResult FilterProducts(string productID)
{
    // do your filtereing based on productID.
}
```

`FilterProducts` will be called every time when user hits the drop-down to get filtered value.

Comment: This answer was very helpful. I'm trying to do the same thing, but the different is that I'm using a popup editor. In that case, the id return by the javascript filter function is always empty.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the Editor Template.  It will bind to a dropdown without it.  You can use this, like you had, just minus the template:

```
c.ForeignKey(x => x.ProductID, (List<Product>)ViewData["products"], "ID", "ProdName")
```

or

```
c.ForeignKey(x => x.ProductID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["products"], dataFieldValue: "ID", dataFieldText: "ProdName")
```

And for filtering, you can just invoke `.Filterable()` on the grid.

Comment: The question is not about filtering the column.

Comment: @ataravati, Really?  Seems he asked "I want to modify collection of ProductID column in the grid after page is loaded based on value selected on other drop-down defined outside of the Grid."  To me, that means filtering, even though he didn't say "filtering". Since there were other grammar errors, I assumed he didn't speak English and maybe did not know the word for filtering.  But modifying a collection on the page using a dropdown to do it seems to me to indicate filtering.  The other part seemed like he needed to figure out how to display the FK column on the page, which my examples show.

Comment: My apology! Looking at his own answer, it seems to me that the original question was not clear enough.

Comment: So if you didn't -1, who did?

Comment: I did. But, I can't take it back.

Comment: Thanks for owning up to it, +1.